# drone (Docker-Compose in docker?)

Tags: docker, drone.io

I’d like to do

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Seems like `plugins/docker` is able to do what I want, but it fails if I don’t specify the publish-related stuff. I want to use it without publishing.

Another alternative could be services, but I try always failed

the code from [docs.drone.io/docker_dind](https://docs.drone.io/examples/service/docker_dind/)

```
kind: pipeline
name: default

steps:
- name: test
  image: docker:dind
  volumes:
  - name: dockersock
    path: /var/run
  commands:
  - sleep 5 # give docker enough time to start
  - docker ps -a
  - docker-compose -v # new

services:
- name: docker
  image: docker:dind
  privileged: true
  volumes:
  - name: dockersock
    path: /var/run

volumes:
- name: dockersock
  temp: {}
```

Error:

```
/usr/drone/bin/init: line 23: docker-compose: not found
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `docker:dind` container does not seem to have "docker-compose" installed. You can try using the `docker/compose:1.23.2` container. You need to mount the docker socket file if you intend on using your host docker resources (ie. images, networks). Otherwise, you need to mount your directory with the docker-compose file to the `/code` directory.

docker/compose image reference: https://hub.docker.com/r/docker/compose/

See code below for reference:

```
kind: pipeline
name: default

steps:
- name: test
  image: compose:1.23.2
  volumes:
  - name: docker_sock
    path: /var/run/docker.sock
  commands:
  - up -f /drone/src/docker-compose.yaml
volumes:
  - name: docker_sock
    host:
      path: /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: thank you, I change the image: docker/compose:1.23.2 and commands: - docker-compose -v

[docs.drone - Specify the image to start the container from. Drone supports any valid image from any compatible Docker registry, including private registries.](https://docs.drone.io/user-guide/pipeline/steps/)

Comment: 0

in my case it says: MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "h6wwnv9s7zdmpdrh2ken9vv1qmj2vzdv" : hostPath type check failed: /var/run/docker.sock is not a directory

Comment: ```volumes:
  - name: docker_sock
    host:
      path: /var/run/docker.sock

steps:
- name: test
  image: compose:1.23.2
  volumes:
  - name: docker_sock
    path: /var/run/docker.sock
  commands:```

Comment: @custer any idea?

Comment: When I try out the accepted solution I get the error: 'Invalid or missing pipeline section'. Any ideas?

Comment: Pass your YAML through a linter. Many times an extraneous newline or space might wreak havoc.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this yml for drone run docker compose :

```
- name: publish
  image: docker/compose:1.25.0-rc2-alpine
  commands:
    - docker-compose -f <docker compose filename>.yml up -d
  volumes:
    - name: dockersock
      path: /var/run/docker.sock
  depends_on:
    - build
```